# Changing the innerHTML back to its original value but getting "undefined" using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

100% stuck on a homework assignment...

I have some simple JavaScript with the intent of changing the background image and text of a div upon mouseover over certain images. However, what I am trying to execute now is to revert the div back to its original state upon mouseout.

I am able to revert the divs background color with

```
document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = "";
```

Essentially killing the background image and forcing it to revert to the background color that is there upon page load.

Now what I'm trying to do is store the original innerHTML text "Hover over an image below to display here." as a variable

```
var originalText = document.getElementById('image').innerHTML;
```

and then call it back when I need it.

```
  function unDo() {
        document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = "";
        document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = originalText;
```

however,

```
var originalText = document.getElementById('image').innerHTML;
```

is returning "undefined", which means I've goofed up somehow when storing the variable, right? I've tried innerText as well and that doesn't seem to do much for me. Below is the full HTML and JavaScript below.

```js
/*Name this external file gallery.js*/
var originalText = document.getElementById('image').innerHTML;

function upDate(previewPic) {
    document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = previewPic.alt;
    document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = "url('" + previewPic.src + "')";

    /* In this function you should 
       1) change the url for the background image of the div with the id = "image" 
       to the source file of the preview image
       
       2) Change the text  of the div with the id = "image" 
       to the alt text of the preview image 
       */

}

function unDo() {
    document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = "";
    document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = originalText;

  

    /* In this function you should 
   1) Update the url for the background image of the div with the id = "image" 
   back to the orginal-image.  You can use the css code to see what that original URL was
   
   2) Change the text  of the div with the id = "image" 
   back to the original text.  You can use the html code to see what that original text was
   */

}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 2%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #b3b3b3;
}

#image {
    line-height: 650px;
    width: 575px;
    height: 650px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #8e68ff;
    background-image: url('');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    font-size: 150%;
}

.preview {
    width: 10%;
    margin-left: 17%;
    border: 10px solid black;
}

img {
    width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Photo Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gallery.css">
    <script src="js/gallery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="image">
        Hover over an image below to display here.
    </div>

    <img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">

    <img class="preview" alt="With My Boy" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">

    <img class="preview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt="Young Puppy" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">

</body>
</html>
```

note: I'm not allowed to change the HTML for this assignment. Only the JavaScript. You do NOT have to do my homework for me. However, a hint in the right direction would be nice.

[screenshotoflocalenvironment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t31CP.png)

Comment: I've added a Stack Snippet to the question, and it seems to work fine. A little oddly, since the CSS is missing, but still working.

Comment: Try to put your javascript code at the end of the body tag.

Comment: Works ok to me, just move CSS to it's place from JS field

Comment: Tested, and works as expected (from description). Can't seem to replicate the issue.

Comment: i put in the CSS. and its working. like you all said. which is hella embarassing. But why isn't it working on my local environment? x.x ugh

Comment: Well there are at least two places where you might have errors which we cannot see here: `css/gallery.css` and `js/gallery.js`. You might have an error there.

Comment: Have you looked for errors in the console? My guess is that the problem is that your script runs before the DOM is ready, so `document.getElementById('image')` returns `undefined`.

Comment: 2like if I had the wrong file paths?

im confident thats not it. because the other portion of javascript I wrote is working...just not the innerhtml part...

Comment: @Lennholm hmm thats a thought. I am getting the undefined issu in the console.

Comment: Because your script runs in the head, i.e. before the body is parsed and you haven’t wrapped that part of the code in a `DOMReady` event handler. The rest of the script runs fine because `document.getElementById('image')` is actually the last thing that happens in your script, thanks to hoisting.

Comment: I put a screenshot of my local and the error im getting in the post..ill keep trying to move things around. i mean technically the javescript is right, so I could submit it..but not sure if this is going to show up on my teachers computer or not x.x...

Comment: @Lennholm thank you for your answers I super appreciate it (actually the file path comment was for ivan ).

Comment: i'm feeling pretty uh..silly as about now. thanks so much for everything :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like this could be happening because your script tag in your html is above the body.

When you declare the "original text" variable at the beginning of your script, the page hasn't loaded yet, and so it comes back undefined, because it can't find anything in the document with an "image" class.

Sometimes it loads quick enough maybe, other times it doesn't

Instead, move your script tag in your html to right below the body tag. So the script loads after the body has loaded. Should fix it.

**additional tip.

Store your element (i.e: the "image") in a variable instead of calling getElementbyId multiple times. Every time you do this javaScript searches the entire DOM which is resource intensive in bigger applications and can get pretty slow. Just a pet peeve of mine.

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I spent like 2 hours on this x.x. Sometimes the simplest answer is the best answer. I'm technically not supposed to move the javascript in her HTML file, but i will do so with a comment ;)

Comment: Javascript is **not** loaded asynchronously unless explicitly configured to do so. A `<script>` tag without the `async` or `defer` attributes block everything else the script is guaranteed to run before anything below the tag gets parsed.

Comment: @gyadav I suggest implementing a DOM ready event handler instead. That way you can make your code work without breaking your instructor’s rules for the assignment.

Comment: @Lennholm I actually just thought the same thing. We haven't gone over them yet. but i'm perusing through mdn to see how I can do that. another great suggestion. maybe they will be impressed x.x.

Comment: Mark ! I was wondering why everyone stores those as variable. I thought it was just for ease of typing. Didn't realize it was searching the entire DOM every time, but that makes sense. Wow guys I'm gonna go back to class with way too much knowledge haha.

Comment: @Lennholm I stand corrected. That was one piece I wasn't 100% sure on. Good to know.

Comment: @gyadav do you mind accepting my answer for this question? if you aren't sure how it's here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @MarkSmith I'm so sorry I forgot to accept you answer! I did it now  :/

Answer (score 0):

First save the background color in a variable :

```
z = document.getElementById("mydiv").style.backgroundColor;
```

Then on mouse out, restore this color :

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").style.backgroundColor = z;
```

It works for me. My full code is :

```
`   <script>
    var z;
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("mydiv").onmouseover = function() {mouseOver()};
    document.getElementById("mydiv").onmouseout = function() {mouseOut()};
    });

    function mouseOver() {
      z = document.getElementById("mydiv").style.backgroundColor;
      document.getElementById("mydiv").style.backgroundImage = "url('londoneye.jpg')";
    }

    function mouseOut() {
      document.getElementById("mydiv").style.backgroundImage = "";
      document.getElementById("mydiv").style.backgroundColor = z;
    }
    </script>`
```

The html is :

```
<div id="mydiv" style="width:400px; height:400px; background-color:yellow;margin-left:50px; margin-top:50px;">
```